# how to bind SVG elements to data?

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm looking for feedback on my coding technique for designing an interface with Javascript/SVG. I am new to these languages, as I have recently abandoned my specialization in Adobe Flex.

The software will be a generic interface to map source signals to destination signals. Connections are represented by a grid, with rows/columns representing source/destination signals:

```
X X X X | destination A
X O X X | destination B
X X X X | destination C
X X X X | destination D
---------
1 2 3 4
```

In this -beautiful- diagram, the "0" represents source 'signal 2' is mapped to 'destination B'.

I am concerned with binding the data (connection objects) to the view (SVG elements). Here's how I did it:

the data is stored in a 2D array: connections[nSources][mDestinations]

In the view, for each item in the 2D array of connections, I create an SVG element with its ID as "celln,m" ("n,m" corresponds to its row/col indices) and add it to the DOM. I found this to be a very simple way to access any SVG element, by using document.getElementById(…), or to find the row/col a user clicked on by parsing the 'evt.target.id' string.

First implementation works well. But I am concerned because the interface needs to support dealing with dynamic data... sources/destination signals will be added or removed on the fly. Rows and columns can be re-arranged by the user. And it will need to support grouping signals into expandable and collapsable nodes.

A simple example: if a new row is added at index 0, I would need to update the IDs of every SVG element to increase its row by 1.

My specific question: is it ok (good practice, safe, and reliable) to be manipulating the IDs of DOM elements this much??

To see a sample of code (the functions that manipulate the IDs of the SVG elements), please see here:  [sample](http://six39.com/mcgill/libmappergui/sample.txt)

It just seems scary that in a grid of 200x200 (for example), adding a row at index 0 means changing the IDs of 40,000 SVG elements. Does anyone see a problem with that?

Comment: I match data to svg using http://d3js.org/

Comment: I'm trying to avoid libraries for now so I can learn Javascript. And I looked at d3 and it seems mainly for data visualization.. I'm worried there is a bigger learning curve using it to create a completely custom user interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, you will use DOM manipulations to achieve your goals. Suggestion: use MVC pattern. Whenever user adds/deletes row, or rearrange them you modify not DOM, but the model. Then you call some listener/callback that redraws SVG. Personally I would detach the whole table (I would keep all rows in one parent `<g>`, for example) from DOM (with `remove` operation, or smth like it. What library do you use?). Then, I'll recreate it in memory, and only after that I'll attach (`appendChild` to that group) it back. This approach seems to be simple and fast enough.

Comment: Cool. Currently I'm using no library, just straight JS and SVG (because I want to learn them before going for higher level libraries). I will look into MVC now.

But I'm thinking that if I redraw the table every time, won't I would lose out on the possibility to animate the SVG elements? For example, when a row is inserted, I can animate the other rows to slide down. 

Please allow me a bit of time to cleanup/minimize the code so I can post a sample.

Comment: Animation is not a problem. You just draw the table in it's initial state. Then use `<animate>` to perform slide.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, MVC is definitely a good way to go.